# How to enable HTTPS for rocketchat in docker container

Tags: ssl, docker, https, docker-compose, rocket.chat

Recently, I've installed the rocket.chat using docker containers (rocketchat, mongo_db and hubot) but now I would like to enable the HTTPS (SSL) to securize the chat since will be accesible from internet.

Do anyone knows how to setup the SSL files (I have the .key and .cert files) and enable the HTTPS for my rocket.chat ?

To install the tool I followed this guide [LINK](http://braybaut.com/howto-instalando-rocket-chat-en-docker/) (the guide is in spanish, if you need anything else, just let me know)

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
kv

Comment: I don't know if you already have read it, but there is a official rocket.chat guide on configuring the ssl https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/configuring-ssl-reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nginx to create a reverse proxy for that. You can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get the certificates.

Here is a more detailed guide: https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/docker-containers/#5-installing-nginx-ssl-certificate